# Coproducts indexed over a fixed set regarded as functors

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, category-theory

I am self-learning category theory and recently learnt about functor categories. Given that I know some topology, I thought it is possible to regard topological sums indexed over a fixed set as a functor. So take an index set $\mathcal I$ and think of it as a discrete category (its objects are the elements of $\mathcal I$ and the only morphisms are the identities). A functor $\mathcal I\to \mathbf {Top}$ is then just a family of topological spaces indexed over $\mathcal I$, and we may consider the functor category $\mathbf{Top}^\mathcal I$. We let the rule $$\amalg:\mathbf{Top}^\mathcal I\to\mathbf{Top}$$ take a family $X_\mathcal I=\{X_i\}$ to its topological sum/coproduct $\amalg X_\mathcal I=\coprod_{i\in\mathcal I} X_i$ and a morphism $f_\mathcal I:X_\mathcal I\to Y_\mathcal I$ to the unique natural continuous map $\amalg f_\mathcal I :\amalg X_\mathcal I\to\amalg Y_\mathcal I$. I believe this makes $\amalg$ a functor, so that, in particular, having two $\mathcal I$-indexed families of topological spaces which are in bijective homeomorphic correspondence implies that their respective topological sums must be homeomorphic.

Is this argument correct? Does this argument hold if we replace $\mathbf{Top}$ by any category that has at least $\mathcal I$-indexed coproducts?

Comment: You should  use not use $\oplus$ to denote coproducts in categories that are not abelian. You should use $\amalg$; the $\LaTeX$ code is `\coprod` or `\amalg`, depending on whether you want one that is a bit larger and is larger still in displayed equations, or not.

Comment: Yes, this is a functor.

Comment: Fixed! I was not aware of the notational convention.